# PyCharm add remote Python interpreter inside the Docker

Tags: python, docker, pycharm, remote-debugging, boot2docker

So I have set up a docker on my laptop. I'm using Boot2Docker so I have one level of indirection to access the docker. In PyCharm, I can set a remote python interpreter via SSH but I'm not sure how to do it for dockers that can only be accessed via Boot2Docker?

Comment: A remote python interpreter a running container?

Comment: So your container will *have* to be running SSH and exposed to the boot2docker/virtualbox host and you connect to the boot2docker/virtualbox host's exposed ssh port via PyCharm to connect up to your remote Python interpreter.

Comment: Thank you. I'll give it a research on how to forward the SSH.

Comment: @JamesMills, thank you so much. Why don't you post it as answer? And what if I run my container as daemon with a webserver running? Can I attach to a running container instead of `run` cuz I already have run it?

Comment: @JamesMills got two downvotes and a close vote with no comment as to why they think so. Weirdos are everywhere.

Comment: I'm upvoting this because this was a good question. 3 people also favourited so I don't know what's going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay so to answer your question(s):

> In PyCharm, I can set a remote python interpreter via SSH but I'm not sure how to do it for dockers that can only be accessed via Boot2Docker?

You need:

- To ensure that you have SSH running in your container

There are many base images that include SSH. See: [Dockerizing an SSH Daemon](https://docs.docker.com/examples/running_ssh_service/)

- Expose the SSH service to the Boot2Docker/VirtualBox VM.

  docker run -d -p 2222:22 myimage ...
- Setup PyCharm to connect to your Boot2Docker/VirtualBox VM.

  boot2docker ip

---

Attaching to a running container is easy too!

```
$ boot2docker ssh
$ docker exec -i -t <cid> /bin/bash
```

Where `<cid>` is the Container ID or Name (*if you used `--name`*.

Comment: Installed `sshd` and run the services via `supervisord` and now I'm able to connect to interpreter. Thanks James.

Comment: Did you manage to debug a python class using the remote interpreter? i'm able to connect to the interpreter when running a class, however when trying to debug it fails trying to open additional ports.

Comment: What is the failure messages and what ports is it trying to open? (*I'm ignorant of PyCharm and I don't actually use it*).